How to use the Copilot Individual Account with Visual Studio 2022?
I recently purchased a GitHub Copilot Individual subscription and linked my GitHub account to the Visual Studio 2022 personalization screen. I've also installed the Copilot Module via the Visual Studio Installer under Workloads > .NET Desktop Development > Optional section.
However, I'm encountering issues:
The GitHub Copilot button at the top doesn't open the chat window.
I'm unable to use code generation from the main editor.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.11.5. I've struggled to find clear instructions to enable Copilot in VS 2022 after it was integrated into the main installer. Most resources seem to reference the older GitHub Copilot Extension, which isn't applicable anymore.
Could someone please advise what I might be missing? I'd also like to know if anyone has successfully used GitHub Copilot with VS 2022 under these conditions.
Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,
Kritul

P.S.: I am able to use the copilot functionality from the VS Code With GitHub Copilot Extension. So the Subscription is active and working fine. So I believe I am mssing something on VS 2022 Configuration part which needs to be configurred correctly.

I found the issue and its resolved.
Admin controls for GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn
I accidentally had installed this policy in an attempt to get it working. and it was disabling the copilot running. I disabled these policies and the copilot is working.

Run > gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Visual Studio > Copilot Settings


Disable Copilot: Disabled, * Disable Copilot for Individuals: Disabled


I found the issue and its resolved.
Admin controls for GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Learn
I accidentally had installed this policy in an attempt to get it working. and it was disabling the copilot running. I disabled these policies and the copilot is working.
STEPS:
Run > gpedit.msc > Local Computer Policy > Administrative Templates > Visual Studio > Copilot Settings

Disable Copilot: Disabled
Disable Copilot for Individuals: Disabled

